# NetTcpBinding - InsufficientMemoryException Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 67108864 bytes. The amount of available memory may be low

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service, wcf-binding

I have WCF Server (using nettcpbinding) listening for clients. Once client connects, it starts sending the list of objects as one message to connected clients.

This error "InsufficientMemoryException Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 67108864 bytes. The amount of available memory may be low" shows up when we send more objects.

Binding Code

```
 NetTcpBinding myBinding = ServiceHelper.GetBinding(serviceSecurity);
                myBinding.ListenBacklog = 100;
                myBinding.MaxConnections = Int32.MaxValue;
                myBinding.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
                myBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,6);
                myBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 30);
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: What specific reason do you have for changing `MaxBufferSize` away from its default?

Comment: Is that the reason behind the problem? we are not sure about the message size as our system is scalable, we use this value.